# need help to setup node.js

Tags: node.js

I just installed the recent installer of node.js v0.6.13 on my windows system. Now that I have done that what else do I need to do in order to make this work.

my nodejs resides in my Program Files(X86) folder and my js file is in c:\inetpub\www\root folder but then when I opened the node.exe and tried to run the js file in the wwwroot dir it did nothing. Then I copied the js file inside the nodejs folder and tried to run the js file in the console and I got the following error:

**ReferenceError: helloWorld is not defined**

```
at repl:1:2
at REPLServer.eval (repl.js:80:21)
at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:182:12)
at Interface.emit (events.js:67:17)
at Interface._onLine (readline.js:162:10)
at Interface._line (readline.js:426:8)
at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:603:14)
at ReadStream.<anonymous> (readline.js:82:12)
at ReadStream.emit (events.js:88:20)
at ReadStream._emitKey (tty.js:327:10)
```

I am new to this so don't know much about this, can someone revert back with instructions to make this work.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show your source code that's not running? The fact that it's in ``inetpub`` leads me to believe you also don't understand just what Node.js is, yet. (It handles its own web serving needs with an internal HTTP server object, so IIS wouldn't be used.)

Comment: Yes like I said I am new to this, but how does it matter where my project file resides on my system. How can I execute Node.exe to execute my helloWorls.js file.

Comment: No, it doesn't really matter, but Node.js modifies the global scope of Javascript to be different from Javascript in the browser, so without being very careful, the ``.js`` files written for Node.js won't work in the browser (and therefore you wouldn't want them showing up on IIS).

Answer (score 2):

Based on that error, it looks like you are trying to start your JS file from the REPL like

```
node.exe
> hellowWorld
```

If your code is in `helloWorld.js`, you should run it like this:

```
node.exe helloWorld.js
```

Comment: This works! Do you have a link which shows how to setup and configure nodejs without installing npm and other modules.. I thought the installer should work just fine...and I can create my files and open command prompt and run the js files. Is that how it's suppose to work or do I need to do anything else?

Comment: The installer already installed ``npm`` for you, by the way. But you're right about the second part. You can just write directly to the Node.js API and have a working web server for whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @Vish Yep, as David said, you just get the executable, what you do from there is up to you.